# sudo prompts for password even though suders entry specifies NOPASSWD

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to give a specific user the ability to run two commands w/ sudo, without prompting for a password.
This is what I did:

```
# temporarily grant privs to nitsadmin
Cmnd_Alias REBOOT = /usr/sbin/reboot
Cmnd_Alias STOP_START_CRUSHFTP = /var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh

nitsadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: STOP_START_CRUSHFTP, REBOOT
```

The reboot command works exactly as expected, but the crushftp_init.sh command insists on prompting for a password.

Help?

In repy to first comment, this is what I see:

```
nitsadmin@dropbox:~$ sudo /var/opt/CrushFTP10/crushftp_init.sh stop
[sudo] password for nitsadmin:
```

So I'm pretty sure it's `sudo` that is prompting for a password.

Comment: When you are prompted for a password? Does it prompt for a sudo password? What in included in /var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh? Are there any lines in that which prompt for a password?

Comment: Updated the post with anwer to your question.

Comment: Did my answer help you out at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change:

```
Cmnd_Alias STOP_START_CRUSHFTP = /var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh
```

to:

```
Cmnd_Alias STOP_START_CRUSHFTP = /var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh*
```

The alias in the sudoers file needs to match exactly how the command will be run. So `/var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh` does **not** match `/var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh install`

EDIT: This will allow any variation of `/var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh` to be run with sudo without a password. You can change your alias to `Cmnd_Alias STOP_START_CRUSHFTP = /var/opt/Crushftp/crushftp_init.sh stop` if you want to limit to only stop etc.

Comment: Tht did it, thanks!  I actually had a typo on the pthme of the script, so I corrected that too.  All good now, thanks!